# I'm getting "undefined reference" errors and I don't understand why (C++ OO)

Tags: c++, oop, undefined-reference

I've looked at multiple other posts on undefined reference errors, but I can't see any errors in my code. Is there something I'm not catching? I'm compiling with g++ in the ubuntu command line.

Here's my code and the errors from the terminal:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Object.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
    Object* o = new Object(3,6,9);
    o->printVolume();
    delete o;
    return 0;
}
```

Object.h:

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H_
#define OBJECT_H_

class Object
{
public:
    Object(double xSize, double ySize, double zSize);   
    ~Object();
    void printVolume();
private:
    double x,y,z;
};

#endif
```

Object.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Object.h"


using namespace std;

Object::Object(double xSize, double ySize, double zSize){
    x = xSize;
    y = ySize;
    z = zSize;
}

Object::~Object(){
    cout << "Object destroyed." << endl;
}

void Object::printVolume(){
    cout << x * y * z << endl;
}
```

Errors:

/tmp/ccUeuPTn.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to`Object::Object(double, double, double)'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `Object::printVolume()'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to`Object::~Object()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: g++ in the terminal

Comment: I run this:
`~/Desktop/C++ Projects/Forge/src$ g++ -I../include Main.cpp -o Main.o`

Comment: You forgot to compile and link `Object.cpp`.

Comment: How are you linking Object.o to your main?

Comment: The error tells me that you're not compiling or linking your Object class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation appears to have succeeded, and these errors appear to be produced by the linker (or some other kind of post-compilation step) and they are telling you that your `Object::Object(double xSize, double ySize, double zSize)` constructor is nowhere to be found.

It is not enough to let the compiler know about your object by including `Object.h` from `Main.cpp`; this will cause compilation to succeed, but it is only half the story.

The other half of the story is that linking must also succeed, so you have to somehow make `Object.o` available to `Main.o` during linking.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to linux and compiling without an IDE so I didn't know what really went on in the build step, I'll go look into linking and how to do that!

Comment: Good.  Best of luck with that, but if you want my advice, ***do not*** try without an IDE.  It is like trying to build the Eiffel tower with paper clips.  It can be done, but it is going to hurt.